# BERT sentence classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am using the the Python BERT models: https://github.com/google-research/bert

My goal is to build a binary classification model to predict if a news headline is relevant to a specific category. I have a training set of data which has news headline sentences as well as binary values to indicate if the headline is valid or invalid.

I tried to run the run_classifier.py script and the results I obtained do not seem to make sense. The test results file has two columns with the same two numbers being repeated on each row :
[image]

Also in the model parameters for task_name I have it set as: cola, after reading the academic paper for BERT https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf I feel as if this is not an appropriate task name. The paper lists several other tasks on pages 14 and 15 but none of them seem to be appropriate for the binary categorization of sentences based on content.

How can I properly use BERT to classify sentences? I tried using [this guide](https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2019/03/04/state-of-the-art-text-classification-using-bert-model-predict-the-happiness-hackerearth-challenge/). 
But it did not yield the results I had expected.

Comment: It is hard to say what's wrong with your code without looking at it. From my experience, the BERT code in GitHub repository is functional

Comment: @Marat I am using the code as it is in the git hub repository, the only difference is that I am using my own data, which is a TSV file with the id, label, throw away column and the text

Comment: are you sure this matches the expected format?

Comment: @Marat Yes, same file format, and the same column order. How does BERT handle numbers and special characters? would they need to be removed beforehand?

Comment: it depends on the vocabulary. In the worst case, they are treated as OOV tokens

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

For Binary classification task (I assume you have used the `cola` processor), BERT's predictions on the test set goes to `test_results.tsv` file.

In order to interpret `test_results.tsv`, you must know its structure.

The file contains number of rows equalling to number of inputs in the test set. And the number of columns will be equal to number of **test labels**. (Since your task is a binary classification, there will be two columns, column for label 0 and column for label 1).

The value in each column is the softmax value (summing up the values of all the columns for a given row must be equal to 1) indicating the probability of the given class (or label).

If you observe in your case, 0.9999991 and 9.12E-6 (9.12*10^(-6)) are not the same. If you sum them, they equate to ~1. (This can also be interpreted that the test input belongs to the class indicated by label 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
How can I properly use BERT to classify sentences?
```

Take a look at this complete [working code for sentence classification, using IMDB Sentiment Analysis (Binary text classification on Google Colab using GPU)](https://pysnacks.com/machine-learning/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/#binary-text-classification-using-bert)

Basically, you can use Tensorflow and keras-bert to do that. The steps involved are

1. Load and transform your custom data.
2. Load pre-trained models and define network for fine-tuning
3. Train/fine-tune the model using custom data.
4. Classify using the trained model.

Here is brief snippet to help.

```
model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
      config_path,
      checkpoint_path,
      training=True,
      trainable=True,
      seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
  )
inputs = model.inputs[:2]
dense = model.get_layer('NSP-Dense').output
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')(dense)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(
      RAdam(lr=LR),
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'],
)
history = model.fit(
    train_x,
    train_y,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_split=0.20,
    shuffle=True,
)

predicts = model.predict(test_x, verbose=True).argmax(axis=-1)
texts = [
  "It's a must watch",
  "Can't wait for it's next part!",
  'It fell short of expectations.',
]
for text in texts:
  ids, segments = tokenizer.encode(text, max_len=SEQ_LEN)
  inpu = np.array(ids).reshape([1, SEQ_LEN])
  predicted_id = model.predict([inpu,np.zeros_like(inpu)]).argmax(axis=-1)[0]
  print ("%s: %s"% (id_to_labels[predicted_id], text))
```

Output:

```
positive: It's a must watch
positive: Can't wait for it's next part!
negative: It fell short of expectations.
```

Hope that helps.